# Go Project Setup Using IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, go

Just installed version 2016.2.5 of the Community edition of IntelliJ and then installed the Go plugin from:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5047

I followed the wizard for creating a new project but when I come to run a simple hello.go file I get a "Main file is invalid" in the "Run Configurations" dialog.

Does anyone know of a step by step guide to setting up and running the simplest of Go projects?

I've tried GoClipse and now IntelliJ and for both the user documentation is absoluetly crap. It's always the same: they spend ages developing this stuff and proide zero useful documentation!

Thanks
Graham

Comment: I've setup projects on both intelliJ and [VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lukehoban.Go) and found the second to be simpler but then again it's less of an IDE experience. Speaking of an IDE-less experience, there's nothing wrong with following the [Getting Started](https://golang.org/doc/install) guide.

Comment: does not seem so crappy to me https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/wiki

Comment: @NathanCooper I found out that this is the case also. (VSCode is simpler)

Answer (score 4):

I use the plugin with WebStorm, and it is quite an improvement over previous Go IDE attempts.

The issue you run into is quite simple. The auto-generated code does not have the package set to `main`. For that reason, the main file is invalid. You need to manually set the package to main, and add a function called `main`.

My steps to ensure a working Go development environment and set up a new project are:

- Install Go
- Set GOROOT environment variable to Go installation, e.g. `/usr/local/go`
- Create a go directory in your home folder, and set GOPATH to it.
- Install IntelliJ + plugin
- Create a new Go project in a subfolder of `$GOPATH/src`
- Set the Go SDK in IntelliJ
- Create a main .go file and make sure package name is main, and a main function exists.
- Now you can create a proper Run configuration.

For me, this works quite well, including debugging and running unit tests.